# Why does ShellExecute hang when run from a DLL that has been run using RunDll32?

Tags: c, winapi, windows-10, controlpanel

**Background:** We have a Control Panel applet written in C, and a windows service. The applet writes values to the registry that are read by the service. Because it's a service the registry entries are in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, which means the applet needs admin rights to write them. The workaround is to run Control Panel as administrator, but it's annoying to have to explain to customers how to do this (and why).

**Attempted solution:** After extensive reading the only solution I can find is for the applet to use ShellExecute to run a second session of itself with admin rights, thus:

```
HINSTANCE result = ShellExecute(NULL, _T("runas"), _T("C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\rundll32.exe"), _T("shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL C:\\...\\applet.CPL"), NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

However, the call to ShellExecute simply hangs.

As a test, I tried replacing the above line with:

```
HINSTANCE result = ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), _T("C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe"), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

but that hangs as well.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: from where you call ShellExecute ? not from dllmain ?

Comment: Yes, from DllMain. if (ulReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)

Comment: in this case call of course must hang. internally it create threads and **wait** on this threads do some task. but this threads **wait** when your thread leave LoaderLock critical section. classic deadlock

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. Where should I call it?

Comment: i can not know your app logic

Comment: You could talk to the service using some interprocess mechanism instead (network/tcp/udp/pipes/rpc/grpc/com etc.)

Comment: @Dave [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices): "*You should never perform the following tasks from within DllMain: ... - Call the registry functions. ... - call functions in <non-kernel dlls>. Some functions load another DLL, which may not be initialized.*" You *could* have `DllMain()` create its own thread (just not **wait** on it!), but why are you doing this work in `DllMain()` at all and not in your applet's `CPlApplet` callback? Alternatively, consider writing your applet as an EXE instead of as a DLL.

Comment: You have a simple client/server application. Using the registry for sending message is just the wrong way to do this. Even if you could get around the permissions issue, you have a race condition. client sends msg1. Later, it sends msg2. msg2 will _overwrite_ msg1 in the registry entry. So, does the server see msg1, or msg2, or msg1/msg2 [which it should]. How does server tell client that it has recv'ed msg1 and is ready for msg2? And, what about _multiple_ clients? Servers usually listen on a socket. Clients connect to the socket. No msgs lost and each client is separate.

Comment: Also: [What’s the guidance on when to use rundll32? Easy: Don’t use it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130104-00/?p=5643).

Comment: It's not really using the registry to send messages as such, it's basically a setup utility - the service does stuff with files in a specific folder and the control panel applet is used to specify the folder by setting a registry entry. But thanks for all the suggestions, I should be able to work something out.